# How do I fix the importing errors in this code?

Tags: java, import, compilation

I got some source code for an Entertainment Game Bot (for Runescape) years ago and am trying to run it now. However, a lot of the imports are unrecognized by jGrasp and I don't know how to fix the code as I am still only a student. The code for the imports is below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import org.rsbot.bot.Bot;
import org.rsbot.event.events.MessageEvent;
import org.rsbot.script.util.*;
import org.rsbot.script.*;
import org.rsbot.script.wrappers.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.rsbot.event.listeners.MessageListener;
import org.rsbot.event.listeners.PaintListener;
import org.rsbot.script.methods.Game;
import org.rsbot.util.GlobalConfiguration;

@ScriptManifest(authors = { "Enfilade" }, keywords = {"rune", "riot"}, name = "Rune Riot", version = 1.0)
```

The program code is not shown as it is far over the character limit of this post. When I attempt to compile the code it gets a lot of import-related errors such as:

```
RuneRiot.java:17: error: package org.rsbot.bot does not exist
import org.rsbot.bot.Bot;
```

Please tell me what I need to do to solve the import errors and get the code to run properly. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the `org.rsbot` code or jar file? If so, is it in the same folder as your project?

Answer (score 0):

`package org.rsbot.bot does not exist` means that you are missing your `org.rsbot.bot` package.

This can mean one of two things:

1. You don't have the package. *Solution: get the package.*
2. You haven't added the package correctly. You need to get your `jGrasp` to put the Jar or source files (whatever format they are in) for the missing packages on your build path.